# Why can't I see a cookie I sent from Flask to Flutter in the browser?

Tags: flutter, dart, flask, web, cookies

I am creating a Flutter Web app that requires login verification. The user makes a post request with authentication information and then my Flask app with send a cookie back to the client.

Here is the code for the Flask App

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def test():
    resp = jsonify({'message' : 'Logged in!'})
    resp.set_cookie('Set-Cookie', "token", httponly = True, secure = False)

    return resp
```

Here is the Dart/Flutter code where I make the POST request and expect a cookie called 'Set-Cookie'.

```
class HttpService {

  static var dio = Dio();

  static testMethod() async {
    try {
      dio.options.extra['withCredentials'] = true;
      var response = await dio.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test');
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I don't receive this cookie on my browser, but the request is successful and I get the JSON message!

[image: Dev Tools]

BUT, when I make this same request on Postman, **I get the JSON response AND the cookie**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any more details/code.

Comment: AFAIK, the cookie is set on to a domain. You are triggering the request to an IP address 127.0.0.1 , but the flask server is most likely to be started with host name as localhost.  So server sets cookie to localhost (as you use the localhost url), but the request was on to a different name (IP). So the cookie might not get set. If you use `localhost:5000` instead of the IP , it should work

Comment: Thank you! I switched to using localhost:5000 instead and I can actually see the token being set in the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995052/kris), I realized I was making the request from Flutter (Client) to an IP rather than the domain name **localhost**. Because setting a cookie is domain specific, I couldn't see the cookie set in the developer console.

Here is the updated code

```
static testMethod() async {
    try {
      dio.options.extra['withCredentials'] = true;
      var response = await dio.post('http://localhost:5000/test');
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```